# Best way to debug the source-code of typescript dependencies? Npm link? How to remap `/src`?

Tags: typescript, npm, webpack, next.js

I often find myself cross referencing the (un-transpiled) typescript code of my dependencies, and I would find it very useful to be able to step through the **original** (non-transpiled) source code with comments.

Ideally, I'd like to have as universal of a process as possible.

My steps so far are:

1. `npm version <package>` and `npm repo <package>`
2. Clone the repo outside the project, and checkout the hash tagged with my version
3. `npm link <cloned-package-path>` inside of my repo.

Now, the only problem I'm facing is that with some packages, the path for modules is not the same in the repo as it is in the built-and-published package. Often, I would need to replace `<dependency>/<path>` with `<dependency>/src/<path>` everywhere in my code.

So my questions are:

1. Is there an easier way of doing this whole process? Installing source with npm, or some cli tool that does more of this work for me? Surely this is a common need.
2. Is it possible to configure my local environment (I'm using next.js) to do this `/`->`/src/` mapping for me?

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem.

Comment: @SteveTomlin How can I link the typescript source code of my dependencies into my project so that I can step through them while debugging my app.e

Comment: You can only do it if they are exposed to you, ie if you can import them. An alternative is that you fork the original github repo, add code to export the types then create your version into npm maybe as @yourNpmId/npmname. If you don't want to do that - just copy the original types into your project, organised maybe in their own folder under say src/types/npmname.